# Mongoose exec() does not await properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, promise

For some reason, exec() is not awaiting in my code:

```
    let team = <SOME TEAM NAME> //putting manually for testing
    let results = []

    TeamModel.find({ name: team })
        .exec(async (err, docs) => {
            if (err)
                return res.send(Response("failure", "Error occured while retrieving fixtures"))
            
            for(let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){

                let doesExist = await FixtureModel.exists({ leagueName: docs[i].leagueName })

                if (doesExist) {
                    let query = FixtureModel.find({ leagueName: docs[i].leagueName, $or: [{ homeTeam: team }, { awayTeam: team }] })
                    await query.exec((err2, docs2) => {
                        if (err2)
                            return res.send(Response("failure", "Error occured while retrieving fixtures"))

                        docs2.forEach((doc2, index) => {results.push(doc2.toObject())})
                        console.log('during await') //Executes second
                    })

                    console.log('after await') //Executes first
                }
                else { //This section is not required
                    let result = await Communicator.GetFixturesFromLeague(docs[i].leagueId)

                    result.api.fixtures.forEach((fixture, index) => {
                        let newFixture = new FixtureModel({
                            fixtureId: fixture.fixture_id,
                            leagueId: fixture.league_id,
                            leagueName: fixture.league.name,
                            eventDate: fixture.event_date,
                            statusShort: fixture.statusShort,
                            homeTeam: fixture.homeTeam.team_name,
                            awayTeam: fixture.awayTeam.team_name
                        })

                        newFixture.save()
                        results.push(newFixture.toObject())
                    })                    
                }          
            }

            console.log(results)
            res.send(Response("success", "Retrieved fixtures", results))
        })
```

and the result looks something like this:

```
after await
[]
during await
```

and therefore an empty array of results is sent before values are added inside. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: because the code continues when the `query.exec` promise is resolved, not when the callback is finished executing. Try `return docs2.forEach((doc2, index) => {results.push(doc2.toObject())})` or `docs2 = await query.exec()` and then `docs2.forEach...`

Comment: @dikuw I suspected that couldve been the case. Tried your solutions but still didn't work

Comment: `query.exec()` returns Promise only if no callback is passed.

Answer (score -1):

This is a workaround if anyones wondering. Sending the response inside the exec() callback when the forLoop completes bypassing the need for async/await.

```
 if (doesExist) {
                    let query = FixtureModel.find({ league_name: docs[i].leagueName, $or: [{ homeTeam: { team_name: team} }, { awayTeam: { team_name: team} }] })
                    await query.exec((err2, docs2) => {
                        if (err2)
                            return res.send(Response("failure", "Error occured while retrieving fixtures"))

                        docs2.forEach((doc2, index) => {results.push(doc2.toObject())})
                        
                        if(i + 1 == docs.length){
                            return res.send(Response("success", "Retrieved fixtures", results))
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Less messy to revert to plan A and write `let docs2 = await FixtureModel.find(.......).exec();` and leave `res.send(Response('success', 'Retrieved fixtures', results));` outside the `for` loop. Similarly, `let docs = await TeamModel.find({ 'name': team }).exec();`.

Comment: With those two awaits working properly, you can put `try {/* everything */} catch(error) { res.send(Response('failure', 'Error occurred while retrieving fixtures')); }`. This will catch/handle unexpected errors, not just those two specific errors as is the case with the current code.